# How can I make my program sleep for a long time while staying responsive?

Tags: linux, multithreading, asynchronous, rust

I am working on a basic project. I have progressed a lot (first time). And I have encountered an obstacle while trying to make this as a working application.

What I mean by that is, it has a main loop which is infinite. The program will run until user presses `q`. By the way, the program is console application. And I'm working on Linux.

While the program is working, it needs to do some operation `foo` in intervals (eg. 1 hour, 30 minutes, 4 hours).

And yes that's it. I know it doesn't sound complicated but I'm stuck. So what I want is, a Stdin which waits for user input without blocking the application and during that time do `foo` for each 1 hour (let's stick with one hour). But between these `foo`s, I don't want my program spin constantly. Because that causes 100% CPU usage. I want my program work when there is a need for work (eg. When elapsed time is 1 hour or When user presses `q`).

I used a library for manipulating the terminal. And that library has a feature for Stdin without blocking. And I looked it's implementation I saw that it creates another thread to handle this. Since I have to do other feature on my own. I need some help to figure it out.

For elapsing the time without spinning. I tried `sleep` main thread. It did help but it made user input not *responsive*. If the user presses `q` while main thread is sleeping. It waits for it to wake up. I don't want this. I want it to quit immediately if it is idle. (not doing `foo`). if it is doing `foo`, quit after `foo` is done. By the way `foo` is not a heavy computation in my code.

```
fn foo() {
    println!("bar");
}

fn main() {
    let mut instant = Instant::now();
    let one_hour = Duration::from_secs(60 * 60);
    let mut stdin = async_stdin().bytes();

    loop {
        // No need to work
        std::thread::sleep(one_hour);

        // Just to be sure
        if instant.elapsed() > one_hour {
            foo();
            instant = Instant::now();
        }

        // Check for input if there is any
        match stdin.next() {
            Some(Ok(b'q')) => break,
            _ => (),
        }
    }
}
```

```
    foo  stdin                          foo   stdin
     |     |                             |      |
     |     |                             |      | <- Press q
     |     |                             |      |
           |                                    | <- exit here
           |<- Press q and      or              |
           |   exit immediately                 |
           |                                    |
     |                                   |
     |                                   |
     |                                   |
```

I use Rust for my project but pseudocode is fine to me. I am very new to concepts of multithreading and asynchronous. I know they are not the same. I don't even know which is needed for this. Which synchronization objects do I need? Any tips, references, links will help.

Comment: To improve the likelihood of answers, I suggest tagging Rust and probably Linux, and also editing your question to show some code (minimal, just enough to illustrate what you're doing so far).

Comment: Have you considered using CRON instead of putting your app to "sleep"?

Comment: isn't there timer class in rust you can use?

Comment: I have handled to schedule the function call but the thing is I don't want to waste and spin constantly between two schedules. So I put a sleep call in the loop but the drawback is it waits to wake up if the user presses ```q```

Comment: I would check out `mio` and `tokio` for additional ideas to @Angelicos idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run 2 threads and pass messages about exit and wait them with timeout.

```rust
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

type Signal = ();

fn work_queue(end_receiver: mpsc::Receiver<Signal>){
   loop{
      foo();
      match end_receiver.recv_timeout(one_hour){
         Ok(_) => return, // Received signal
         Err(mpsc::RecvTimeoutError::Timeout)=>foo(),
         _ => handle_error(),
      }     
   }
}

fn main(){
   let (send, recv) = channel();
   
   thread::spawn(move || {
    work_queue(recv);
   });
   loop{
      match stdin.next() {
            Some(Ok(b'q')) => {
               send.send(()).unwrap();
               break;
            },
            _ => continue,
      }
   }
}
```

I didn't test this code but I hope that idea is clear.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an example of what you want using [tokio](https://crates.io/crates/tokio).

```
use std::io::{stdin, BufRead, Result};
use tokio::time::{interval, Duration};

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() -> Result<()> {
    tokio::spawn(async {
        let mut interval = interval(Duration::from_secs(60 * 60)); // one hour
        interval.tick().await; // first tick fires immediately, ignore it
        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            // do your stuff
        }
    });

    for line in stdin().lock().lines() {
        if line? == String::from("q") {
            break;
        }
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

The first bit spawns an `async` task that loops forever, waiting an hour between ticks. While the second bit just blocks on user input. Entering `"q"` immediately exits main and destroys the `async` executor. If the task is in the middle of processing, it will wait for it to reach the next `await` before exiting.

Comment: This also works. Seeing this as async version also another plus to me. Thank you.

Comment: @marknikky TBH, using tokio for your case looks like pure overhead because benefits of async apply only when you have a lot of concurent tasks (more than number of CPU cores) which mostly wait on IO. Also, if you work with tokio, you should rather run 2 futures and use select to stop on first. https://docs.rs/tokio/1.4.0/tokio/macro.select.html

Answer (score 1):

I am new to rust as well and I was interested in figuring out your question.  I learned a lot coming up with this answer.  This answer builds on the accepted answer.

Here is a complete and functioning example that addresses a common issue with reading the keyboard: Having to press enter before it reads the `bytes()`

I have also created multiple (two) event producers for `mpsc` and added the timer crate to handle timing.

Note:  This probably won't run properly in vscode or jetbrains environment terminal as it depends on `termion`.  Run it in a true terminal.

dependencies from `cargo.toml`

```
[dependencies]
timer = "0.2.0"
chrono = "0.4.19"
termion = "1.5.6"
```

`main.rs`

```rust
extern crate timer;
extern crate chrono;
extern crate termion;

use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;

use termion::input::TermRead;
use std::io::{stdout, stdin};
use termion::raw::IntoRawMode;
use termion::event::Key;

enum Events { TimerEvent, QuitEvent }

pub fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();

    let timer = timer::Timer::new();
    let timer_tx = tx.clone();

    let _guard = timer.schedule_repeating(chrono::Duration::seconds(3), move || {
        timer_tx.send(Events::TimerEvent).unwrap();
    });

    thread::spawn(move || {
        //This is the trick to reading input one key at a time
        stdout().into_raw_mode().unwrap();
        for input in stdin().keys() {
            if input.unwrap() == Key::Char('q') {
                tx.send(Events::QuitEvent).unwrap();
            }
        }
    });

    loop {
        let value = rx.recv().unwrap();
        match value {
            Events::TimerEvent => work_fn(),
            Events::QuitEvent => return  // return from main()
        }
    }
}

fn work_fn() {
    println!("Timer went off! Do work.");
}
```